# Sum up absolute values in range of cells if a condition is met

Tags: excel, function, for-loop

I want to sum up the absolute value of range E11:E34 if corresponding value in F11:F34 is greater than 0. Example: F11<0 so we do not add E11. And since F13>0, add abs(-4.70) i.e. add 4.70.

What I have tried: `=sumif(F11:F34, ">0", abs(E11:E34))`. This does not work since abs() function accepts a number instead of a range

[image: Data]

Comment: Use `SUMPRODUCT`.

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(ABS(E11:E34),N(F11:F34>0)) or =SUM(ABS(E11:E34),F11:F34>0)

Comment: Or you could try sumifs(e11:e34,e11:e34,">0",f11:f34,">0")-sumifs(e11:e34,e11:e34,"<0",f11:f34,">0")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SUMPRODUCT`is the way to go. Here's how you can use it to reach your goal:

This formula will sum the absolute values in `E11:E34` only if the corresponding value in `F11:F34` are greater than 0.

Step by step, we will use the first 4 values of your data:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(E11:E34)*(F11:F34>0))
```

```
E11:E14 = [-1.66, 2.05, -4.70, .48]
F11:F14 = [-.0184, -0.265, 3.154, 1.412]
```

ABS(E11:E14):
- converts `E11:E14` to absolute values.
i.e `[1.66, 2.05, 4.70, 0.48]`

(F11:F14>0):
- checks if values in `F11:F14` are > 0
`[FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE]`
- `TRUE` becomes `1` & `FALSE` becomes `0`.
i.e. `[0, 0, 1, 1]`

Multiplication:
- formula multiplies the two arrays
i.e.
- `1.66 * 0 = 0`
- `2.05 * 0 = 0`
- `4.70 * 1 = 4.70`
- `0.48 * 1 = 0.48`
Result: `[0, 0, 4.70, 0.48]`

**final output: `0 + 0 + 4.70 + 0.48 = 5.18`**

Comment: Wow this works! Thanks for the help. If you wouldnt mind, can you explain how the syntax works in this case. Tried searching online but dont seem to get it

Answer (score 1):

I will offer this as an alternative as it's OK to use it with full column references so you don't have to worry about specifying the exact range:

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,A:A,">0",B:B,">0")-SUMIFS(A:A,A:A,"<0",B:B,">0")
```

Of course if you have other stuff that you don't want to include in those columns then you won't get the right result.

[image]

If you have Excel 365, you can also use this method, assuming you have no blanks amongst the data:

```
=LET(ColumnA,N(TOCOL(A:A,1)),ColumnB,N(TOCOL(B:B,1)),SUM(ABS(ColumnA)*(ColumnB>0)))
```